# WASP dependency checker reporting security issue from cache for a library that is forced to a later version

Tags: java, build.gradle, owasp-dependency-check

OWASP dependency checker found an issue in the **snakeyaml** library version 1.3. Since this was included in the project as a transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter which is also automatically included as a dependency of spring-boot library.
So, I forced version 2.0 of snakeyaml in the *build.gradle* file.

```
configurations {    
    all {
        resolutionStrategy {           
            force 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I can see in the external library list, snakeyaml version 2.0 is present. But after running the dependency checker again, I can see it's reporting snakeyaml 1.3 version again, but from the **gradle cache location**.

I removed the cache, but reloading gradle reinstates the older version along with version 2.3.

Q1. Is there any way we can configure OWASP dependency checker not to omit the libraries in the cache, only look for used libraries?
Q2. Is there any other way to handle the situation?